# when starting the application, Postman throws a 404 error

Tags: java, spring, postman

I'm trying to write a currency exchanger project, I'm trying to test it in Postman, but error 404 comes out. There may be such a problem there is not correctly specified postman_id and exporter_id, it's just my guesses

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "27454191-473..........",
        "name": "CurrencyExchanger",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "........"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "/currencies",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Date",
                        "value": "multipart/form-data",
                        "type": "default"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Date",
                        "value": "multipart/form-data",
                        "type": "default"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Da",
                        "value": "multipart/form-data",
                        "type": "default"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": [
                        {
                            "key": "name",
                            "value": "zxc",
                            "type": "default"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "code",
                            "value": "Dead inside",
                            "type": "default"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "sign",
                            "value": "z",
                            "type": "default"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:8080/currencies",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "8080",
                    "path": [
                        "currencies"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
```

```
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet(name = "indexCurrenciesServlet", value = "/currencies")
public class CurrenciesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        currencyRepository = (CurrencyRepository) config.getServletContext().getAttribute("currencyRepository");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(resp.getWriter(), currencyRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String code = Utils.getStringFromPartName(req, "code");
        String name = Utils.getStringFromPartName(req, "name");
        String sign = Utils.getStringFromPartName(req, "sign");

        if (Utils.isNotValidCurrenciesArgs(code, name, sign)) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Не правильно введены данные. Пример: code = 'USD', name = 'US Dollar', sign = '$'");
            return;
        }

        if (currencyRepository.findByName(code).isPresent()) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT, "Валюта с таким кодом уже существует");
            return;
        }

        currencyRepository.save(new Currency(code, name, sign));

        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hyu6.jpg)

I tried to reinstall tomcat, at first I thought there were problems with it

Comment: It´s not related to the postman_id nor the exporter_id values, it seems more like an issue when the app started, could you share the logs when the app starts?

Comment: @DeadSpock, 
Connected to server
[2023-06-13 07:46:17,567] Artifact CurrencyExchanger:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
13-Jun-2023 19:46:23.753 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.

Comment: @DeadSpock  SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[2023-06-13 07:46:24,220] Artifact CurrencyExchanger:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2023-06-13 07:46:24,220] Artifact CurrencyExchanger:war exploded: Deploy took 6,654 milliseconds

Comment: 13-Jun-2023 19:46:27.192 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [D:\Scene\tomcat9version\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\manager]
13-Jun-2023 19:46:27.861 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Scene\tomcat9version\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\manager] has finished in [670] ms